# Accessing contents of HTML response with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frisby.js

I need to automate some API tests using frisby.js and javascript, but I am having trouble accessing some data of a HTML response, most propabily because the response is not in JSON format.

Below is my code

```
var frisby = require('frisby');
frisby.create('Get some information')
    .get(someUrl)
    .after(function (err, res, body) {
        console.log(body);
    })
    .toss()
```

Below is the result of `console.log(body);`function

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
  <title>MDpay default response template for web</title>
</head>
<body OnLoad="OnLoadEvent();" >
<form name="downloadForm"
      action="https://someurl"
      method="POST">
  <input type="hidden"
         name="PaReq"
         value="eJxVUdtuwjAM/ZWKDyBJCWuLjCUuk8YDE2JMYk8opN6ogBTSdIK/X1LK2PISn5PYxz6G1c4STd9I15YQ5lRV6ouiIh92krgnZQdhMVrSGeGbbFWUBkWXd2Ngd+hTrN4p4xCUPo9nrygznkgOrIVwJDubIudc8HCA3Qgw6kg42m+V2W960828zOmwWVHlgDVPoMvaOHvFJPN6dwC1PeDOudOAMWABAHu0sKhDVPnkS5HjgtPc6Zyvx5PLm5YFlcXabd8/1TMfAgs/IFeOMOYi8d09RaI/4PFAJsAaHtQxqOJq+RH1eTf03jJwCkKjG+g3U/1lwLtpyegrZjLzvd8R0OVUGvI//ES/MeRUaYy8aLiBPYaYvARXtfN2xWkvTkUabG1wKFV4P0QqbrUCABYyWLsx1m7TR/+2/APkDqQg">
  <input type="hidden"
         name="TermUrl" value="https:someurl">
  <input type="hidden"
         name="MD"
         value="402277:56F8FBC5FC36742423302C8EFF56C796E7B123FC61132EA2AD89A389A02C4093:4243:##100100000">
  <!-- To support javascript unaware/disabled browsers -->
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="templates/preloader.gif"/><br/>
    <noscript>
      <center>Please click the submit button below.<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></center>
    </noscript>
  </div>
</form>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" >
  function OnLoadEvent() {
    document.downloadForm.submit();
  }
</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is do you know a way to reach `value`'s of `PaReq`, `TermUrl` and `MD` HTML tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do some string operations to reach the values, below is the code which worked for accessing these values

```
var pareq = body.substr(body.search('name="PaReq"'),600);
pareq = pareq.substring(pareq.indexOf('value="')+7,pareq.indexOf('">'));

var termUrl = body.substr(body.search('name="TermUrl"'),200);
termUrl = termUrl.substring(termUrl.indexOf('value="')+7,termUrl.indexOf('">'));

var md = body.substr(body.search('name="MD"'),250);
md = md.substring(md.indexOf('value="')+7,md.indexOf('">'));
```

If you have better ways to solve this, please let me know, 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'fake' DOM element and set it's innerHTML, then you can query it like a normal web page.

```
var el = document.createElement('html');
el.innerHTML = '<input name="PaReq" value="foo">';

el.querySelector('input[name=PaReq]').value; // "foo"
```

If you are running the test in a node.js environment you will need to also use `jsdom` for example.. see https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#passing-objects-to-scripts-inside-the-page for example